# Why append don't work, pass by reference?

Tags: python

I have writtern the below codes

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.append(4)
```

Why there is nothing inside `b`?

Comment: append does not return what you think it does.
First do `a.append(4)` then `b = a`.

edit: Oscar's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: By the way: Python doesn't support pass by reference, everything is passed by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `append` doesn't return the modified list - it simply adds the new element, modifying the list in-place and returning `None`. To get the effect you want, do this instead:

```
b = a + [4]
```

Notice that the above creates a new list, whereas using `append` modifies the same list.

Comment: But if I do a = [1,2,3], b = a, a.append(4). B would be [1,2,3,4]. Why is that?

Comment: Take a look at using deepcopy

Comment: @JOHN because `b` is a reference to `a`. In fact, `a` and `b` would be the exact, same list! - they're just two variables pointing to the same object, and anything you do to `a` will be reflected in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what it is you want the value of b to be. But here is what it is when you run the code.

The value of b is None, because it is the return value of the method (.append())
Every method will return a value. In this case it is None, because a.append(4) is appending to the array a. Returning a value means to SIMPLY return a value. This doesn't require a value.

Answer (score 0):

append returns None, That's why there is nothing in b. Your list a will be modified and added 4.

If you realy want to add 4 in b then you can try a + [4]